# How to Change the launch animation of an Application?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, launching-application

Is there any way to change the Application launching animation programmatically ?
whenever I am launching a application its animating like its coming from the bottom of the screen but I want it to come from the Top of the screen.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The launch animation is decided by the Launcher app of the phone. You can't and shouldn't control that. User will have customer launcher applications on their phone and you shouldn't try to control that.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the AlphaAnimation , and apply it to the layout of your Activity like this , in the **onCreate()** method :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstace);
this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
RelativeLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.idLayout);
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ;
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setDuration(1200);
//apply the animation ( fade In  or whatever you want) to your LAyout
layout.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

**top_down.xml** in anim folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

and

**down_top.xml** in anim folder

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%p" android:duration="5000" />
     <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="5000" />
 </set>
```

and apply to this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.top_down, R.anim.down_top);
```

Comment: this will help while switching from one activity to another in the Application. I want to change the animation while launching the application. :)