# Where is default animation present in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, android-animation, android-source

I want to know where is default animation available in android?

When I click the application icon, there is transition animation. Let me know where the transition animation is available?

I checked in [frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r47/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/) but still I couldn't figure out which class default animation been added.

1. When I open application for second or third time, transition comes from bottom to top. I need to modify with no animation. So let me know where those default animations are available?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for these animations :
(Default activityOpenEnterAnimation)

You can override it in your themes.xml file

[image: Animation.Activity]

Try this for Alpha animations in your launcher activity :

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.idLayout); // Your layout
AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f , 1.0f ) ;
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setDuration(1200);
//apply the animation ( fade In ) to your Layout
layout.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: I changed everything but still I am getting the same issue. Somewhere android is maintainging default animation which comes from bottom to top. I am not able to figure out in android 10.

Comment: i think app launching animations are decided by launcher application and can't be changed.

Comment: I have entire source code of aosp. I just need to know where those default animations are available. http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r47/xref/packages/apps/

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48210764/how-to-change-the-launch-animation-of-an-application

Comment: Yes but I don't know where exactly I need to change to restrict by changing the default animation in launcher because I have n number of applications. (Launcher, Browser, Settings etc., ) So commonly if I change the animation, globally for all applications, it will change. But currectly it comes from bottom to top.